# How to programmatically retrieve information from LDAP

Tags: asp.net, ldap

I am running an ASP.Net page on IIS7, and developing in VS 2008. Currently, I have user authentication being done through an LDAP connection. Once the user logs in, on one page they have a form with some basic information about them (such as their name, email address, country, and the like) and I wish to pre populate some of these fields from information already stored in the LDAP. In particular their given name and email addresses. The question is, using C#, how do I actually retrieve this information?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you're on .Net 3.5 SP1, in that case you can use the [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace that **greatly** simplifies this.

Here's a sample:

```
var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomaincontroller");
var u = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pn, userName);
var email = u.EmailAddress;
var name = u.DisplayName;
```

[Here's a full list of properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal_properties.aspx) you can grab.

Comment: Thanks, a small question though. I am unsure about what to use for the string you've used 'mydomaincontroller' for. The ldap authentication has been done by using ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider in the Web.Config . Presumably I would have to provide the LDAP url as long as a username and password. When/Where/How is this done?

Comment: @Jacob - I normally connect to a variety of domain controllers...you can also just do `var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);` to grab whatever domain controller windows picks or...alternatively, you can do `var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "my.server.com", "user", "pass");`  Here's a full list of options: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.principalcontext.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be just what I wanted!